# extracting an array of object array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects.

Each object has a `langauges` array in it.

I need to extract all languages of all objects and they have to be unique (language shouldnt be multiple times in this array)

This is what I did so far:

```
this.countries.map((country) => {
      country.languages.forEach((language) => {
        this.languages.push(language);
      });
    });
```

Not sure how ideal is it regards performance. Actually it shows all languages even multiple times.

Any ideas for the best way (performance) to make a list out of objet property array?
[image]

Comment: please add the data as well.

Comment: Please provide the final array object structure with array to be extracted structure

Comment: How large is your array that you care so much about performance?

Comment: Data added, updated question

Comment: please add the data in text form in literal syntax.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's a simple array `[0] => "lang" [1] => "lang2"`

Comment: @TheUnreal I agree with Nina Scholz. It's always important to provide a sample and add it in text format, at least I like to debug code before providing answer, and no one's gonna type all that code long hand ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your requirement this is probable what you are looking for

```js
 var arr=[{"country":"India","languages":[{"languageId":"1", "languageName":"English"},{"languageId":"2", "languageName":"Hindi"},{"languageId":"3", "languageName":"Bengali"}]},
 {"country":"USA","languages":[{"languageId":"1", "languageName":"English"},{"languageId":"4", "languageName":"French"},{"languageId":"5", "languageName":"Italian"}]},
 {"country":"China","languages":[{"languageId":"1", "languageName":"English"},{"languageId":"6", "languageName":"Chinese"},{"languageId":"7", "languageName":"German"}]}];
   function extractLang(arr){
    var langArr=Array();
    arr.forEach(function(item, index){
      var cur_langs=item.languages;
    cur_langs.forEach(function(lang, ind){
     if(!langArr.includes(lang.languageName)){
      langArr.push(lang.languageName);
     }
    })
    });
    console.log(langArr);
   }
   extractLang(arr);
   //
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set in order to be sure that the elements are unique:

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

So in your case:

```
this.languages = new Set();
```

And instead of doing push, do it:

```
this.languages.add(language);
```

This will keep your uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const languages = Array.from(new Set(
    [].concat(...this.countries.map(country => country.languages))
));
```

Comment: not what I excepted, I need unique values and seperated values. Your code does that: http://i.imgur.com/YjMxtLO.png